# Axis2 : Use Rampart for security with JAX-WS (WS-Security)

Tags: jax-ws, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I'm using Axis2 JAX-WS service. I defined WSDL and used wsimport tool to generate the classes.
It uses sun-jaxws.xml file and does not need services.xml file.

Could some one help me out to integrate Rampart (WS-Security) for authentication and security.
Example is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point for rampart, with some basic examples: http://blog.sweetxml.org/2007/12/rampart-basic-examples-how-you-add-ws.html